# TensorFlow - Low GPU usage on Titan X

Tags: performance, profiling, gpu, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

For a while, I have been noticing that TensorFlow (v0.8) does not seem to fully use the computation power of my Titan X. For several CNNs that I have been running the GPU usage does not seem to exceed ~30%. Typically the GPU utilization is even lower, more like 15%. One particular example of a CNN that shows this behavior is the CNN from DeepMind's Atari paper with Q-learning (see link below for code).

When I see other people of our lab running CNNs written in Theano or Torch the GPU usage is typically 80%+. This makes me wondering, why are the CNNs that I write in TensorFlow so 'slow' and what can I do to make more efficient use of the GPU processing power? Generally, I am interested in ways to profile the GPU operations and discover where the bottlenecks are. Any recommendations how to do this are very welcome since this seems not really possible with TensorFlow at the moment.

Things I did to find out more about the cause of this problem:

1. Analyzing TensorFlow's **device placement**, everything seems to be on gpu:/0 so looks OK.
2. Using **cProfile**, I have optimized the batch generation and other preprocessing steps. The preprocessing is performed on a single thread, but the actual optimization performed by TensorFlow steps take much longer (see average runtimes below). One obvious idea to increase the speed is by using TFs queue runners, but since the batch preparation is already 20x faster than optimization I wonder whether this is going to make a big difference.

   ```
   Avg. Time Batch Preparation: 0.001 seconds
   Avg. Time Train Operation:   0.021 seconds
   Avg. Time Total per Batch:   0.022 seconds (45.18 batches/second)
   ```
3. Run on multiple machines to rule out hardware issues.
4. Upgraded to the latest versions of CuDNN v5 (RC), CUDA Toolkit 7.5 and reinstalled TensorFlow from sources about a week ago.

An example of the Q-learning CNN for which this 'problem' occurs can be found here: https://github.com/tomrunia/DeepReinforcementLearning-Atari/blob/master/qnetwork.py

Example of NVIDIA SMI displaying the low GPU utilization: [NVIDIA-SMI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shmpF.png)

Comment: Does changing the batch size change the behavior? Or making the network more complex?

Comment: +1 on increasing mini batch size. The Volatile GPU-Util number could have as much to due to memory utilization than anything else. With 12GB on a Titan X you have alot of head room there. If your model does not take up much memory you can fill it up with bigger batches.

Comment: I have performed a small experiment to study the influence of changing the batch size. Below are the results for feeding the batches of sizes N = 1..512 to the training operation. Each training example is an 84x84x4 tensor of type `tf.float32`.

Results are here: http://pastebin.com/xrku9AjW

As you can see the GPU Utilization does not seem to change significantly, or it even decreases when increasing the batch size. The time measurements are averages over 100 batches and are recorded using `time.time()`. Any clues on what is wrong here?

Comment: Can this still be reproduced with 1.0?

Comment: Have you ever managed to figure it out? I have a very similar problem on my GTX1060.

Comment: Hi, Did you solve that problem? I am also facing the same problem when I am running my tensorfow code GPU utilization only going to 35%.

Answer (score 1):

With the more recent versions of Tensorflow (I am using Tensorflow 1.4), we can obtain [runtime statistics](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/graph_viz#runtime_statistics) and visualize them in Tensorboard.

These statistics include compute time and memory usage for each node in the computation graph.